Setting `IsTabStop` on `TextBox` makes it unclickable
I would like to prevent entering TextBox via TAB key, so I set IsTabStop to false, but it completely prevents the control to have focus by simple mouse click on it?
How can we prevent Tab Stopping, but allowing control to work normally if clicked?
I tried changing the IsTabStop of TextBox, but it prevents it to have focus.

From the doc:

if IsTabStop is false, the control cannot receive input focus. (If you try to set focus programmatically, by calling the Focus method, Focus returns false).

UPDATE
You can wrap the TextBox with a Grid and use it to switch IsTabStop:
<Grid
    x:Name="TextBoxGrid"
    Background="Transparent"
    Tapped="TextBoxGrid_Tapped">
    <TextBox
        x:Name="TextBoxControl"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        IsTabStop="False"
        PlaceholderText="TextBox #2" />
</Grid>

private void TextBoxGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxControl.IsTabStop = true;
    TextBoxControl.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    TextBoxControl.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    TextBoxControl.LostFocus -= TextBoxControl_LostFocus;
    TextBoxControl.LostFocus += TextBoxControl_LostFocus;
}

private void TextBoxControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxControl.IsTabStop = false;
    TextBoxControl.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}


Updated my answer with a workaround.

Thanks @andrew-keepcoding!  Although I totally do not know why we need this kind of workaround, in WPF, the simple set of IsTabStop was enough to make it skip tab navigation and left the mouse clicking work.
I was thinking of something like this but could not figure it out...
I tested it and it work flawlessly!!
